# ls command that excludes directories that end in

Tags: regex, unix

I am writing a shell script that takes the directory listing and does stuff with it.  However,  there are directories that need to be included, in this case, anything that begins with "feature", and excluded,  in this case, any directory that ends in "tmp"

I did some research,  and found the `--ignore`  option,  which takes a regular expression.

Being terrible at regex, I looked up "find anything that ends with"  and I ended up with this:

```
ls -d --ignore=\A[a-z]*tmp\z feature*
```

This does list all of the directories that begin with "feature"  but still lists directories that end in "tmp"

Does someone know this magic?

Comment: Somewhat related: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems here.  `\A` and `\z` are not available in most regex dialects; but moreover, the argument to `--ignore` is not a regex at all.  You are looking for a shell glob (wildcard) pattern.  (Somewhat imprecisely, the [GNU `ls` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html) simply calls this a "shell pattern". This option to `ls` is a GNU extension, BTW.)

```
ls --ignore='[a-z]*tmp' feature*
```

Notice also the quoting around the pattern; without quoting or escaping, the shell will attempt to perform its own backslash processing and wildcard expansion on the value.

(Some people like to say wildcards are "a kind of" regular expression, but that's really not helpful IMHO. They are two different formalisms with different capabilities and different syntax. Newcomers are already confused that there are different dialects of regular expressions.)